# Tweaking the sequence elements of an IQueryable with a Select clause?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to do something that feels like it should be really simple, but has turned out to be a real headache.  I'm `Select`ing from an `IQueryable` and instead of creating a new object, I want to "tweak" the one that I'm projecting.  Here's what I want to be able to do (`context` is a `DbContext`, and I'm using a code-first approach):

```
var eventsToReturn =
    ((IQueryable<Event>)
        context.Events
        .OrderByDescending(evnt => evnt.TakesPlaceOn)
        .Skip(startAt)
        .Take(numberToReturn)
    )
    .Select(evnt =>
        {
            evnt.UnmappedUsersCount = evnt.Users.Count();
            return evnt;
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```

This is nice because Entity Framework doesn't have to actually get all the `User` entities associated with each event, and can use an aggregate `COUNT` function to simply get the number of users.  However, it doesn't work, because the `IQueryable` version of `Select` wants a lambda statement with no method body that can be converted into an expression tree.  So, while the above doesn't work, this does:

```
.Select(evnt => evnt)
```

... and so does this:

```
.Select(evnt => evnt.Users.Count())
```

I have solved the problem, but my way seems rather long-winded.  Here's my approach:

```
var eventsToReturnData =
    ((IQueryable<Event>)
        context.Events
        .OrderByDescending(evnt => evnt.TakesPlaceOn)
        .Skip(startAt)
        .Take(numberToReturn)
    )
    .Select(evnt =>
        new {
            Event = evnt,
            UnmappedUsersCount = evnt.Users.Count()
        }
    )
    .ToList();

var eventsToReturn = eventsToReturnData
    .Select(evntData => {
        evntData.Event.UnmappedUsersCount = evntData.UnmappedUsersCount;
        return evntData.Event;
    })
    .ToList();
```

So I'm projecting the main `Event` object into an anonymous object, as well as the one tiny `int` that I want to add to it, and then doing a whole new `Select` on `eventsToReturnData`, which works this time because `eventsToReturnData` is an `IEnumerable` (so the lambda can have a method body), just to tweak the `Event` object by setting the `UnmappedUsersCount` integer that I got from the first query.

Is there a simpler or more elegant way to do this?  I want to avoid EF having to retreive all the users for each event, so it's no good just using `Event.Users.Count()` on what is returned by the `IQueryable`'s `Select` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage the `Expression` class to build a tree at runtime but that is so much work and code that it would be justified only if you had to do such a thing a lot of times.

If this pattern occurs only once or rarely in your code this is the best you can do.